# Counting 2 elements

Tags: c#

The title is somewhat confusing, let me try to explain what I'm trying to do.
I'm receiving 2 strings at the same time, they are connected to each other on each *receive* but may or may not be related to the next received data.

So, if I receive this combination:

```
ID24
PART2
```

I want to create a variable that will increment a counter on that combination, eg.:

```
ID24-PART2++ (1)
```

Then, on the next receive round, I could get this:

```
ID59
PART2
```

So I would increment that particular counter:

```
ID59-PART2++ (1)
```

To finalize, if I received again:

```
ID24
PART2
```

Then:

```
ID24-PART2++ (2)
```

Hope I explained myself well. Performance is important.

Maybe some sort of array:

```
data["ID24"]["PART2"]++;
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is add the two strings together, and add it to a dictionary as a string:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>,int> stringDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>,int>();
```

Then for each string pair that you recieve:

```
Tuple<string,string> stringTuple = new Tuple<string, string>(string1, string2); //string1 and string2 are the strings you recieve

if(stringDict.ContainsKey(stringTuple))
    stringDict[stringTuple]++;
else
    stringDict.Add(stringTuple, 0);
```

If you were wanting to iterate this through a `foreach` loop you would use similar to this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<Tuple<string, string>, int> kvp in stringDict)
{
    Tuple<string, string> keyTuple = kvp.Key;
    int tupleCount = kvp.Value;
}
```

Comment: If you did that then "AA" and "B" would be considered equal to "A" and "AB".

Comment: How so? `"AA" + "B" = "AAB"` is the same as `"Hello " + "World" = "Hello World"`? I understand that a `tuple` would possibly work better, but the string addition will work.

Comment: Yes, "AA" + "B" = "AAB", and "A" + "AB" = "AAB" *as well.  You now have two entirely different pairs of strings that are being mapped to the same dictionary key.  You should see two different pairs each with one count, not one pair with two counts, but your code won't do that.

Comment: I get what you mean now, I edited mine to reflect a `Tuple` that will have the desired result.

Comment: btw how would I iterate stringDict in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

Have a dictionary that maps a pair of strings to an integer:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> dictionary = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use a hashmap.  Take your two inputs, cast them to a string and then store them in the hashmap with the two inputs as a key and a counter as the value.